# SSH login with defined authentication methods

Tags: ssh, authentication, pam

I have a small server, and I would like to be able to login using SSH with 2 methods:

- Public key
- Password *and then* a PAM made in Python

I successfully installed `libpam-python`, and added this line to `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
auth   requisite   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_python.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/my_pam.py
```

For the sake of example, let's assume my python pam works, and just asks for another password.

Here are the relevant parameters in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# PAM
UsePAM yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Regular password
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Authentication Methods
# Either an authorised public key, or the password + another one (python pam).
AuthenticationMethods publickey password,keyboard-interactive:pam
```

Unfortunately, this does not work:

```
# I am not using an authorized public key
me@client:~$ ssh user@myserver
user@myserver's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
user@myserver's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
user@myserver's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

*My password is correct!* If I change the parameters back to their default value, my password is recognized and I can log in!

The issue seems to be the `AuthenticationMethods` parameter. If I remove it, it works:

```
me@client:~$ ssh user@myserver
Python PAM password:
Password OK!
END OF PYTHON PAM. 
Password: 
user@myserver:~$
```

Note that the classic `user@myserver's password:` has been replaced by a stern `Password:`.

Unfortunately, even if it works, I can't choose the order of the 2 methods (I wanted the reverse order), and the classic password method seems to have been replace by a PAM version, which I don't know, thus bother me a bit.

**How can I solve this issue?**